# ImageView cut the right side of my image

Tags: android, image, imageview

I have a ListView that displays items containing an icon and text. The icon, when I put pictures of different sizes in xxhdpi (96x96), xhdpi (64x64), hdpi (48x48) and mdpi (32x32), cut the right side and bottom of the image. The images that i have only the folder xxhdpi (96x96) are not cropped.

[image: Only first is inside the four folders, the rest of images is only in xxhdpi folder]

Only cropped image (the first) is inside xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi and mdpi the rest is only in xxhdpi.

This is the layout that contains the ImageView:

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_container_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:alpha=".8"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:paddingBottom="9dp"
                android:paddingLeft="18dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:paddingStart="18dp"
                android:paddingTop="9dp"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_section_bikes" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can u please explain me with more detail, i cant get actually it what u trying to say..

Comment: Ok... The image in the ImageView is cropped on the right side and the bottom side. But that only in the case where the image is stored in the four directories for different screen densities. If I leave one copy in, for example, the folder xxhdpi, the image is displayed correctly. But if I put the picture in the 4 directories, the image is cropped.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a folder for higher densities and a folder for lower densities: drawable-xxxhdpi (192x192 px) and drawable-ldpi (32x32 px). In addition, each vector image have a margin of 25% the size of the entire image (ie: the drawable png in folder drawable-xxxhdpi has a size of 192x192, but the image has a size of 144x144 px).

For more references visit: http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Thank you.